# Enabling GPU acceleration on body element

Tags: html, css, browser, gpu

Somebody just asked this on IRC: is it at all possible or feasible to set their `document.body` to use `translateZ(0)` and what the benefits or downsides of that would be.

Whereas he was not actually morphing/animating/moving/scaling the body itself, his logic was mostly to offload the rendering/repaint work of his whole document to his GPU and work through inheritance for the bits that DO change.

My guess was the benefits of that would be scant and the downsides will be more - i.e. affect cleartype/kerning, make it render inconsistently based upon chipset implementations, make it fail in VMs like VirtualBox on OSX etc and may make certain browsers crash, (dependent on what's happening, eg. `node-webkit`) - so my advice was to keep `translateZ` for elements intended to move/change in a particular way. Also, debugging issues etc would be much easier if there are single points to anchor to, not the whole document. But... am I wrong?

Can somebody with a greater understanding of browsers please shed some light on the best practice here and what goes on behind the scenes when an element is handled by the GPU.

Answer (score 0):

The transform: translateZ(0); declaration triggers GPU acceleration in modern desktop and mobile browsers. This seems to be the most effective way of triggering GPU acceleration.  This is applicable when using modern CSS attributes, such as box-shadow, inset box-shadows, text-shadows, and CSS animations.  This reduces the strain on the client-side CPU, and allows the graphic processor to handle the heavy-lifting.  Keep in mind, in some scenarios, the clients GPU may be less efficient, or non-existing. If you are using polyfills, such as CSSPIE, your initial reaction may be to use this for browsers that will require a pollyfill injection, this isnt true considering the browsers that dont support CSS3 dont recognize the translate property.